# Reusable Panel Container Template Architecture in Angular

Tags: css, angular, panel

I'm intermediate in my Angular understanding and am trying to wrap my head around how to accomplish the following.

I want to create a UI component that can be used to contain heterogeneous content, likely from other components.

It displays a certain amount of the content with an overflow ellipsis affordance.  [image: Panel Layout]

It has a full border and a header.

The issue is that due to the border and functionality, I want this component to *contain* the content controlled by some other component.

I've looked at inheritance, directives, and manipulating the view container. Each solution looks is intuitively displeasing as is either impossible or would seem to place a heavy load on the DOM render.

Comment: <ng-content>? https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks Julia!

Comment: Good. I added it as answer. Please accept it if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

Read detailed tutorial at http://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content